# Draw a palette box in LaTeX

Tags: color, boxes

Is there a way to build a structure like the following in Latex?

[image: Color palette]

They're probably just boxes, but I have very little experience with Latex and I'm not sure how to get this result.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Here are some examples, not boxed, but with palletes. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/color-manipulation/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\newcommand\palbox[2]{{\sffamily\fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax\footnotesize%
  \fcolorbox{gray!50}{gray!10}{%
    \stackengine{8pt}{%
      \colorbox[RGB]{#1}{\rule{60pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{60pt}}%
    }{%
      \color{black!60}\stackengine{12pt}{\##2}{\saycolors{#1}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
    }{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
  }%
}}
\newcommand\saycolors[1]{\saycolorsaux#1\relax}
\def\saycolorsaux#1 #2 #3\relax{R:#1 G:#2 B:#3}
\begin{document}
\palbox{1 103 143}{01678f}\quad
\palbox{221 109 16}{dd6d10}\quad
\palbox{18 54 69}{123645}\quad
\palbox{120 121 124}{78797c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I hadn't at first realized that the top line of text is actually the RGB converted to hex.  Thus, one can calculate that from the RGB and can reduce the number of arguments from two to one.  I use the `binhex.tex` package for the conversion into hex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\input binhex.tex
\newcommand\palbox[1]{{\sffamily\fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax\footnotesize%
  \fcolorbox{gray!50}{gray!10}{%
    \stackengine{8pt}{%
      \colorbox[RGB]{#1}{\rule{60pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{60pt}}%
    }{%
      \color{black!60}\stackengine{12pt}{\intohex{#1}}{\saycolors{#1}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
    }{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
  }%
}}
\newcommand\saycolors[1]{\saycolorsaux#1\relax}
\def\saycolorsaux#1 #2 #3\relax{R:#1 G:#2 B:#3}
\newcommand\intohex[1]{\#\intohexaux#1\relax}
\def\intohexaux#1 #2 #3\relax{\twodigithex{#1}\twodigithex{#2}\twodigithex{#3}}
\newcommand\twodigithex[1]{\ifnum#1<16\relax0\fi\MakeLowercase{\hex{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\palbox{1 103 143}\quad
\palbox{221 109 16}\quad
\palbox{18 54 69}\quad
\palbox{120 121 124}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing (twice).

Comment: @Sigur Thanks. (thanks).  Macros make the world go round.

Comment: What I liked is that the 1st argument is a list of numbers separated by spaces, not comma. Very useful.

Comment: @Sigur Often, one can structure the `\def` arguments (in this case, of `\saycolorsaux`) to achieve the desired parsing.  When that proves too difficult, I always fall back on the `listofitems` package, which is unsurpassed in its ability to parse a difficult construct into an expandable array structure..

Comment: What about using `\MakeLowercase{}`?

Comment: Congratulations!!! Nice work.

Comment: Such a great work, thanks you so much. I was in a hurry to get it for a document but I'll make sure to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using `tikz`. It uses `expl3` to automatically calculate the hex value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds, shadows}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__criw_rgbtohex:n
  {
    \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT { ##1 } < { 16 } { 0 }
        \int_to_hex:n {##1}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \__criw_palette_box:n
  {
    \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \definecolor { palettecolour } { RGB } {#1}
    \begin {tikzpicture}
      [
        node~distance = 4mm,
        inner~sep = 0mm,
        every~node/.style = { font = \sffamily\footnotesize }
      ]
      \node (colour)
        [
          fill = palettecolour,
          minimum~width = 3cm,
          minimum~height = 3cm
        ]
        { } ;
      \node (hex)
        [
          below = of~colour.south~west,
          anchor = north~west
        ]
        { \#\__criw_rgbtohex:n {#1} } ;
      \node (rgb)
        [
          below = of~hex.south~west,
          anchor = north~west
        ]
        { R: \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 }~
          G: \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 }~
          B: \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 } } ;
      \begin {scope} [ on~background~layer ]
        \shadedraw 
          [
            left~color = white,
            right~color = black!10,
            draw = black!15,
            drop~shadow =
              {
                shadow~xshift = 0.5mm,
                shadow~yshift = -0.5mm,
                fill = black!40,
                opacity = 1
              }
          ]
          (current~bounding~box.south~west) + (-2mm, -2mm)
          rectangle
          ( [ shift = { (2mm, 2mm) } ] current~bounding~box.north~east) ;
      \end {scope}
    \end {tikzpicture}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \PaletteBox { m }
  {
    \__criw_palette_box:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\PaletteBox{1, 103, 143}\quad
\PaletteBox{221, 109, 16}\quad
\PaletteBox{18, 54, 69}\quad
\PaletteBox{120, 121, 124}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]