# tikz convert color string to hex value

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to convert a color string to hex value in tikz.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,outer sep=0,minimum size=1cm}}
\def\dy{1}
\foreach \col [count=\i] in {red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,purple} {
    \def\mycol{\col!40!gray}
    \node[box,yshift=1cm*\i*\dy,fill=\mycol,label=left:\mycol] (main) {ABC};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I wish show `red!40!grey` to something like `#xxxxxxxx` but not show how can do such convert!

Comment: I believe this question also deals with the issue of color conversion to hex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475007/draw-a-palette-box-in-latex  See also the `binhex.tex` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your answer is definitely a great step towards a solution but does it also work if the colors are defined in the way the OP does? If so, your answer may also be mentioned under [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482662/121799).

Comment: I think combining my answer with the `colorinfo` package will allow what needs to be done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this (with `\extractcolorspecs` and `\convertcolorspec` from the `xcolor` package, loaded by the `tikz` package)?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,outer sep=0,minimum size=1cm}}
\def\dy{1}
\foreach \col [count=\i] in {red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,purple} {
    \def\mycol{\col!40!gray}
    \extractcolorspecs{\mycol}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}
    \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{HTML}\hex
    \node[box,yshift=1cm*\i*\dy,fill=\mycol,label=left:\mycol] (main) {\#\hex};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not done in `tikz`, but rather using the `colorinfo` package to extract color information, and the `binhex.tex` package to convert the color info into hex format.

Extending my answer here [Draw a palette box in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475007/draw-a-palette-box-in-latex/475014#475014) to allow the specification in terms of LaTeX color specification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,colorinfo}
\input binhex.tex
\newcommand\palbox[1]{{\sffamily\fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax\footnotesize%
  \fcolorbox{gray!50}{gray!10}{%
    \stackengine{8pt}{%
      \colorbox[RGB]{#1}{\rule{60pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{60pt}}%
    }{%
      \color{black!60}\stackengine{12pt}{\intohex{#1}}{\saycolors{#1}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
    }{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
  }%
}}
\newcommand\saycolors[1]{\saycolorsaux#1\relax}
\def\saycolorsaux#1 #2 #3\relax{R:#1 G:#2 B:#3}
\newcommand\intohex[1]{\#\intohexaux#1\relax}
\def\intohexaux#1 #2 #3\relax{\twodigithex{#1}\twodigithex{#2}\twodigithex{#3}}
\newcommand\twodigithex[1]{\ifnum#1<16\relax0\fi\MakeLowercase{\hex{#1}}}

\newlength\rcomp
\newlength\gcomp
\newlength\bcomp
\newcommand\colcomponents[1]{\expandafter\colcomponentsaux#1\relax}
\def\colcomponentsaux#1,#2,#3\relax{%
  \setlength\rcomp{\dimexpr255\dimexpr#1pt\relax+.5pt\relax}%
  \setlength\gcomp{\dimexpr255\dimexpr#2pt\relax+.5pt\relax}%
  \setlength\bcomp{\dimexpr255\dimexpr#3pt\relax+.5pt\relax}%
}
\newcommand\truncatergb[1]{\expandafter\truncatergbaux#1\relax}
\def\truncatergbaux#1.#2\relax{#1}
\newcommand\xpalbox[1]{%
  \colorlet{mycolor}{#1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\colorInfo{mycolor}}%
  \colcomponents{\colorValue}%
  \edef\Rcomp{\truncatergb{\the\rcomp}}%
  \edef\Gcomp{\truncatergb{\the\gcomp}}%
  \edef\Bcomp{\truncatergb{\the\bcomp}}%
  \edef\tmp{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Rcomp
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\space
    \expandafter\Gcomp\expandafter\space\Bcomp}%
  \expandafter\palbox\expandafter{\tmp} = \colorbox{mycolor}{#1}%
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\xpalbox{blue!40!red!25}
\xpalbox{blue!60!green!45}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One more example base on @quark67's answer:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=M1 going below,node distance=0]
    \tikzset{box/.style={draw,outer sep=0,minimum width=2cm,on chain=M1}}
    \def\dy{1}
    \foreach \col [count=\i] in {red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,purple,
        {rgb,255:red,0; green,255; blue,0},
        {rgb:red,1;green,1;yellow,1}} {
        \extractcolorspecs{\col}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}
        \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{HTML}\hex
        \node[box,fill=\col,label=right:\col] (main) {\#\hex};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]